# zxing library , MonochromeBitmapSource and BufferedImageMonochromeBitmapSource missing?

Tags: barcode, zxing

I'm using zxing library

Following code giving compile time error after adding zxing 2.1 dependency

```
MonochromeBitmapSource source = new BufferedImageMonochromeBitmapSource(bufferedImage);
```

i replaced it with

```
LuminanceSource lumiancesource = new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(bufferedImage);
BinaryBitmap source = new BinaryBitmap(new GlobalHistogramBinarizer(lumiancesource));
```

**I'm correct ?????** As project still in other compilation errors i can't run and check , so need help .

kindly give suggestions .

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MonochromeBitmapSource` is not a class in the project. Your second snippet looks correct.